# Suggestions for variable names in DBeaver

Tags: plsql, sqlplus, dbeaver

I have written a script in PL/SQL and when I write the same code in DBeaver, the suggestive names for the variables in the DECLARE block do not show up. Can anyone help me, as when I would have a bigger script, this would be a problem to keep track of every local variables. This problem is not there in other IDEs like dbForge or Datagrip by Jetbrains.

Also, tell me how do i run PL/SQL scripts in DBeaver. When I run a SQL*PLUS script in DBeaver, it throws random errors, but that same script would just run fine in DataGrip and other IDEs.

Comment: It throws random errors? They are different every time and completely unpredictable?

Comment: DBeaver has popups for database internal types (tables, views, etc) but not for user defined variables. If you cannot keep track of your local variables then perhaps they are not named well or your procedure is trying to do too much and should be broken down into its components; or just use another IDE.  As for how to execute a script look on the far left of the SQL editor window. There is a series of icons,hover over those to see what they do, or select SQL Editor from the menu bar then select the option you want. **Disclaimer:** I use DBeaver only for Postgresql and SQLite

Comment: @Belayer correctly said, I found that DBeaver cannot compete with other IDEs like Datagrip and DBeaver. DBeaver Community support is also worse. I was using Oracle Database and DataGrip helped me the most in times of need.